# Interaction lagrangian neutral vector boson $Z_µ$ of mass $M_Z$ with Dirac fermion $ψ$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism

Let’s consider the following lagrangian density describing the interaction between a neutral vector boson
$Z_µ$ of mass $M_Z$ with Dirac fermions $ψ$
$$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L_{free}}+\mathcal{L_{int}}=-\frac{1}{4}Z^{\mu\nu}Z_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}M_z^2Z^{\mu}Z_{\mu}+\bar{\psi}(i \displaystyle{\not} \partial -m)\psi+g\bar{\psi}\sigma_{\mu\nu}\psi Z^{\mu\nu} +d\bar{\psi}\sigma_{\mu\nu}\gamma_5\psi Z^{\mu\nu}$$
with
$$\mathcal{L_{int}}=g\bar{\psi}\sigma_{\mu\nu}\psi Z^{\mu\nu}+d\bar{\psi}\sigma_{\mu\nu}\gamma_5\psi Z^{\mu\nu} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \sigma_{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{2}[\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}]$$
My problem is:

> I would not have been able to write $\mathcal{L_{int}}$ starting only from $\mathcal{L_{free}}$.
>   Someone can link to a reference where it is schematized how to do or explain me.

Starting point:

I know that once all the generic terms have been written, the renormalizability condition applies, i.e. couplings $M^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \ge0$. 
However, I do not know methodologically what procedure to follow to write all the terms.

Comment: The first of the two interaction terms, the Pauli moment one, you also have in QED for photons, so you could find it in advanced QM books, like Sakurai's....

Comment: Specifically, [JJ Sakurai, Advanced QM](https://www.amazon.com/J-Sakurai-Advanced-Quantum-Mechanics/dp/B008VR1ZAS), eqns (3.208)-(3.209) review the [Gordon Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_decomposition) of the Standard EM spinor current, isolating this, Pauli moment, term from the bland convective term. The Pauli moment term $F_{\mu\nu}\bar{\psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\psi$ summarize's the merman's magnetic interactions.

Comment: "summarizes the fermion's"  is what the spell-checker monster should have started from...